# How to get lines of a file with exactly 3 characters in Linux

Tags: linux, command, wc

I need a command to find the lines of a file that have 3 characters. I do the `command wc -w field.txt` to list how many lines, but now I need to know the lines with 3 characters, exactly.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -c -E "^.{3}$" input.txt
```

This will count (-c) the number of lines which match the regex (-E) "^.{3}$", which is "start of line, exactly three of anything, end of line".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing the code, I will give a hint. Read each line of the file, then use the `wc -c` command or bash builtins to get the number of characters and make a comparison to get if the line has three or whatever characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop and print the lines whose length is 3 (in bash):

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
   if [[ ${#line} == 3 ]]; then
      echo $line;
   fi
done < file
```

The same can be done using awk:

```
awk '{if(length($0) == 3) print}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

The wc (word count) command in Unix/Linux operating systems is used to find out number of newline count, word count, byte and characters count in a files specified by the file arguments.

The following are the options and usage provided by the command.

```
wc -l : Prints the number of lines in a file.
wc -w : prints the number of words in a file.
wc -c : Displays the count of bytes in a file.
wc -m : prints the count of characters from a file.
wc -L : prints only the length of the longest line in a file.
```

When using options ‘-c‘ and ‘-m‘ with ‘wc‘ command will print the total number of bytes and characters respectively in a file.  Example

```
[root@domain ~]# wc -c domain.txt

112 domain.txt

[root@domain ~]# wc -m domain.txt

112 domain.txt
```

Comment: Does that in any way answer the quesion?!